# IgniteUI IgTileManager does not maintain the correct maximized tile location when switching layouts

Tags: jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am trying to set different layouts based on window size and orientation. One tile is larger than the rest and is considered the "maximized" tile. The rest are "minimized". When I click on a "minimized" tile it swaps it with the "maximized" position.

**WORKS:**
 If I do not swap any tiles, and just change the layout, then everything is correct, and the largest tile position is considered the "maximized" tile.

**DOESN'T WORK:**
If I first click on a "minimized" tile to swap it with the "maximized" tile, then change layouts, the tilemanager will use the incorrect position to hold the "maximized" tile.

The maximized tile index should reference which tile configuration in the items list is the maximized tile, but this appears to change when tiles have been swapped.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/72apwsb2/

```js
     var optionsWide = {
                items: [
                    { rowIndex: 0, colIndex: 1, rowSpan: 3, colSpan: 6 },
                    { rowIndex: 0, colIndex: 0, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 },
                    { rowIndex: 1, colIndex: 0, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 },
                    { rowIndex: 2, colIndex: 0, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 }
                ],
                minimizedState: ':not(.maximizedContainer)',
                maximizedState: ':not(.minimizedContainer)',
                maximizedTileIndex: 0,
     };

     var optionsNarrow = {
                items: [
                    { rowIndex: 0, colIndex: 0, rowSpan: 6, colSpan: 3 },
                    { rowIndex: 6, colIndex: 0, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 },
                    { rowIndex: 6, colIndex: 1, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 },
                    { rowIndex: 6, colIndex: 2, rowSpan: 1, colSpan: 1 }
                ],
                minimizedState: ':not(.maximizedContainer)',
                maximizedState: ':not(.minimizedContainer)',
                maximizedTileIndex: 0,
     };

     $(function () {         
         $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsWide);
         $('#wideBtn').click(function () {
             $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsWide);
         });
         $('#narrowBtn').click(function () {
             $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsNarrow);
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the tile configuration and merging it with existing configuration on button click. If you destroy the widget first and then initialize it with the new configuration your sample will work. I have updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72apwsb2/3/).

```
 $(function () {         
     $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsWide);
     $('#wideBtn').click(function () {
         $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager("destroy");
         $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsWide);
     });
     $('#narrowBtn').click(function () {
         $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager("destroy");
         $('#layoutContainer').igTileManager(optionsNarrow);
     });
 });
```